# How to calculate the voltage of these capacitors?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhA2CG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

My task is to represent the voltage values of nodes a, b and c by using known parameters such as V<sub>0</sub>, R<sub>1</sub>, C<sub>1</sub>, etc.

The question is, **before** the voltage source V<sub>0</sub> is powered on and is able to provide some electric potential, the voltage values across all capacitors are 0, which means we have to consider the process of capacitors' charging rather than simply the steady state of this circuit. And the expressions I need should include the charging process.

I presumed that there is a difficult differential equation waiting to be solved. Am I right? Any advice on how should I analyze a circuit like this? And more importantly, how can I solve this one?
(multiple horrible capacitors are in this circuit, because it is actually a part of RC thermal model, where actually the fewer resistors and more capacitors are what we usually deal with.)

Comment: Do you need the response starting at T=0 when V0 is turned on, or is the steady state after everything has settled good enough?  The latter is rather easier.

Comment: T =0 when V0 is turned on, when capacitors need to be charged

Comment: This question has all the appearance of a homework question. Unless you make some effort to show what solution you have started and where you are getting hung up this is likely to be closed. And hopefully some other poster here does not spool off a complete answer for you because you learn nothing from that.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop  response starting at T=0 when V0 is turned on.

Comment: Practically, you don't want to hand-calculate the response of a circuit like this. Enter it into a simulator and hit "go".

Comment: @Michael Karas  Please consider me as a hopeless student who will accomplish nothing if I chose solving circuit equations as my major. This question may be meaningless if treated as a pure electric circuit question. If no tricks can be applied on it, a long trivial solution would not be necessary.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a HW question with zero attempt to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Write out the mesh equations for the circuit using KCL.  And remember that I = C * dv/dt for current flowing through each capacitor.

The result should be a third order differential equation.

The voltages a,b,c can be found by solving the third order differential equation.

The result in the time domain should look like the a sum of decaying exponentials.

You can double check your answer by making sure that at infinite time the result looks like the circuit solution with all capacitors open.